# Complete proof that if last list element not in list, prepending will not be making it so

Tags: idris

Having done exercise 9.1 of the book Type Driven Development with Idris I can not get one of my proofs to be complete. The exercise is to make the `isLast` function work. It should return a proof of that a value is the last value of a `List`. It works, but unfortunately `notLastInTailEqNotLast` is not total.

```
data Last : List a -> a -> Type where
     LastOne : Last [value] value
     LastCons : (prf : Last xs value) -> Last (x :: xs) value

lastNotNil : Last [] value -> Void
lastNotNil _ impossible

lastNotEq : (contra : (lastValue = value) -> Void) -> Last [lastValue] value -> Void
lastNotEq contra LastOne = contra Refl
lastNotEq _ (LastCons LastOne) impossible
lastNotEq _ (LastCons (LastCons _)) impossible

notLastInTailEqNotLast : (notLastInTail : Last xs value -> Void) ->
                         Last (y :: xs) value -> Void
notLastInTailEqNotLast notLastInTail LastOne = ?hole
notLastInTailEqNotLast notLastInTail (LastCons prf) = notLastInTail prf


isLast : DecEq a => (xs : List a) -> (value : a) -> Dec (Last xs value)
isLast [] value = No lastNotNil
isLast [lastValue] value = case decEq lastValue value of
  Yes Refl => Yes LastOne
  No contra => No (lastNotEq contra)
isLast (x :: xs) value = case isLast xs value of
  Yes last => Yes (LastCons last)
  No notLastInTail => No (notLastInTailEqNotLast notLastInTail)
```

How can I fill `?hole`?

I have seen the solution here: https://github.com/edwinb/TypeDD-Samples/blob/master/Chapter9/Exercises/ex_9_1.idr. I understand how that works around my problem using `lastNotCons` and I can my solution to work that way, but it seems like a workaround. The proof I want to provide seems trivial to me: if I have proof that an element is not the last element in a list then another list with that list appended will still not have that element as the last element in the list (i.e. `notLastInTailEqNotLast`).

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a possible to prove `notLastInTailEqNotLast`, because it is not correct. Here is a counter example: `0` is not the last element of the empty list `[]`, but if you prepend `0` to the empty list you suddenly get that `0` is the last element of the new list.

Another way to see it is when you are trying to fill in `?hole`, you have `Void` as your goal, so that must mean you should have a contradiction in your context, but the context looks like so

```
`--   phTy : Type
      value : phTy
      notLastInTail : Last [] value -> Void
     ---------------------------------------
```

But your only candidate for contradiction is `notLastInTail`. If you squint at its type you'll see that it's simply your `lastNotNil` theorem, i.e. it's not contradictory.

Comment: Damn! Of course :) Thanks a lot! I am slowly getting the hang of this. I saw the lack of a contradiction, but just don't have enough confidence/experience yet to know that I should reevaluate my theorem. Instead I though there was something wrong with my Idris skills.

Comment: You are welcome! This is why I like this technology :)